# python: cannot find files outside current directory

Tags: python

I am running python (2.7) from a command prompt in Cygwin. I normally pass a filename to my python code and retrieve the filename with: sys.argv[1]. I get python to check for the existance of the file (using os.path.exists) prior to opening.

This has worked even if I specified a file as "../dir1/dir2/file_name". As of today Python cannot find ANY files (even thoughb they are all there) if the filename includes a path.

eg: for a prog.py in a directory called dir_1

```
 python prog.py          file.txt     :::: works OK

 python prog.py ../dir_1/file.txt     :::: Fails

 >pwd
  ......../dir_1
```

I keep getting "no such file or directory" errors. I get Python to print out the file it is looking for and it has that all OK (it has however turned the ../ etc into an absloute pathname).

I have a feeling soemthing may have got corrupted somewhere. Any ideas?

Russ

Comment: You might need to post some of your code surrounding this error or at least a traceback. As @squiguy suggested, you must be doing something outside of the call to exists()

Comment: I installed Cygwin and tested this out and it seems to handle relative paths just fine. I can successfully use `os.path.exists` on `../../file.txt`, and I can also open it using that notation. You might want to check your cygwin version or something. This problem is just too obscure and not reproducible. Can you maybe update your question with a working example of how to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve those relative references to a proper expanded path.

```
import os

relative = "../"
print os.path.abspath(relative)
# /Users/jdi
```

Its working ok with files that are in your current directory because it doesn't have to resolve anything. But the shell path needs to be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't os.path.exists() check if the path you pass as an argument exists? Are you trying to see if a file exists?

Comment: This is true. The OP must be doing something beyond this to cause an error.

Comment: Maybe it is permissions? You might just want to see if the argument you pass is a file by trying to open it and catch an exception if it fails like this

try:
   open()
except IOError as e:
   print 'couldn't open file'

Comment: I'm trying to open the file. I am using code as you suggested squiguy. When it fails the open I print out the filename. And it expands the relative reference to the full path -so not sure if that's the issue @jdi. Although the filename gets expanded to: /cygwin/c/Users/russ/......, while "os.path.abspath(relative): gets returned as c:\Users\russ\.....  This program (and several others with the same coding) all worked yesterday. Now they all seem to have probs with relative paths - with any file - so I don't think it's permissions either.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that Python does not understand Unix shortcuts like the 'tilde':

```
~/Downloads
```

Won't work
But this will:

```
/home/Castro/Downloads
```

Does this fix your issue?